# help with a math problem that applies the product rule

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

I am trying to apply the product rule to get a percentage rate. my problem is

$0.32\times0.43\times0.05=0.00688$ or $0.68\%$ I rounded off to $0.69$ in fraction form I got $69/100$ people. Now my lab partner says that this is actually $1/145$ people. How is this so?

Answer (score 4):

You've gone wrong by applying the multiplication twice.  Only multiply by $100$ once and you'll get the right answer.  $0.00688 \rightarrow 0.688 \% \rightarrow 0.688 $ (**not** 69) out of $100$, or about $1$ in $145$.  A good way of seeing this is that "%", called "percent", is literally **"Per 100"**.

Comment: I tried 0.688 n fraction form and I got 86/145 why cant I round off to 69 wouldn't it be in its simple form?

Comment: I mean 86/125 dont mind the first message

Comment: You can, it works either way -- but remember: you've already multiplied by 100 once.  86/125 % is still *less than one person out of 100*.

Answer (score 1):

When you done the multiplication you get $0.00688$, so you can get $\frac{68.8}{100}$ or $\frac{69}{100}$ people.

If you do $ \frac{0.00688}{1} = \frac{1}{x} $, then you get $ x \approx 145 $, and that is why your partner says it's $\frac{1}{145}$ people.